# mPDF : text align with p , h1 - h6 in table not work

Tags: php, html, css, tinymce, mpdf

this code not work in table with mPDF php class 
[image]

```
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="contentDetails">
  <td class="contentDetails">
         <h3 style="text-align: right;"><strong>text align right</strong></h3>
         <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>text align center</strong></h3>
         <h3 style="text-align: left;"><strong>text align left</strong></h3>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

i triad use

```
.contentDetails > h3 {display: block;}
```

but not work and between td it's html from Editor tinymce

this full code from script 
and when do output found content the td text align left not right or center

```
<?php

$html = '
<h1>mPDF</h1>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 5px; 
    border-top: 1px solid #777;
    width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="contentDetails">
         <h3 style="text-align: right;"><strong>text align right</strong></h3>
         <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>text align center</strong></h3>
         <h3 style="text-align: left;"><strong>text align left</strong></h3>
     </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>';

include("mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();

exit;
?>
```

Comment: what is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: text-align: in h3 not working ?

Comment: text align with p , h1 - h6 in table not work

Comment: Please post a demo of your issue.

Comment: updating with more details

Comment: It won't work because you are aligning the text within a cell and not the whole cell.

Comment: @ManojKumar is there a solution for this ???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the below code. I think it will help you.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="contentDetails">
     <th align="left"> <h3><strong>text align right</strong></h3></th>
     <th align="center"> <h3><strong>text align center</strong></h3></th>
     <th align="right"> <h3><strong>text align left</strong></h3></th>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

using extra  tags in this.

Comment: the best answer is useing th i used it in a new table in td ContentDetails
look this final code
                        `<td style="padding: 2px;color: #000;border: 1px solid #777;width: 100%;" class="contentDetails">
                         <div style>   <table style="width: 600px;text-align: left;"><tr><th style="width: 200px;text-align: right;">33333333333333</th></tr></table>
                        </td>`

Answer (score 6):

I have prepared a lot of hours a content to print (mPdf v.6). Now i can give an advice to all. Don't use tables to align content or simply hold the content. Almost all css properties of elements work fine. But - but must not be nested in table.

Comment: You're right. - **"But - but must not be nested in table."**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the width of the container which is fitting with the content. Set `table` width to `100%`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="contentDetails">
      <h3 style="text-align: right;"><strong>text align right</strong></h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>text align center</strong></h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: left;"><strong>text align left</strong></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not work yet i think that must be use tcpdf it's better than mpdf

Comment: Alignment with CSS has nothing to do with mpdf or tcpdf :)